# Storing values in DynamoDB while looping through JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store specific values (`id` and `journal` from all the `docs`) from a JSON in my DynamoDB using node.js in Lambda. I loop through the `docs` and in console.log I can actually print out each `id`, but the part for storing the items to DynamoDB is faulty, since my code only stores the very first `id` and `journal` value in DynamoDB. So I guess I can't use the line `await docClient.put(params).promise();` in a loop. What can I do instead?

I use the following JSON: http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA

Here is my current code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const data = await httprequest();

        //date to string

        var d = Date();
        var n = d.toString();
        var iden = Date.now();
        var identifier = iden.toString();

        //add items to DynamoDB

        console.log("LENGTH IS: " + data.response.docs.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.response.docs.length; i++) {

            var params = {
            Item: {
                    date: identifier,
                    time: n,
                    id: data.response.docs[i].id,
                    journal: data.response.docs[i].journal

                },

                TableName: 'employee'
            };

            console.log(data.response.docs[i].id);
            await docClient.put(params).promise();
        }

        console.log('Document inserted.');

        return JSON.stringify(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);

        return err;
    }
};
```

Comment: You can certainly use an await in a loop, whats the partition key and/or sort key in DynamoDB?

Comment: @ug_ Omg you're right. It's because of my key which is date, of course it wouldn't work! Thanks so much!